# How to add onClickListener to a Drawable object in Android?

Tags: android, onclicklistener, drawable

I have a few Drawable objects (images) in a List that are animated.
I wanna create onClickListener (or something like that) to every object to make them disappear from the screen.
I've read, that Drawable objects are non-interactive elements.

In this case, how should I modify the code?
http://pastebin.com/jNzi3qux

Comment: Loop through all the `Drawable`s and check their coordinates against the `MotionEvent`s coordinates. Should be pretty simple.

Comment: I see your problem. Try using a separate class to keep track of each snow flake, that way it will be easier to track their movement. Also use `Bitmap` instead of `Drawable ` it will be easier to draw them on position (no need to translate Canvas).

Answer (score 0):

You just need to test each snowflake bounds against the touch point. Note that depending on how many snowflakes you have this could be slow, in which case you may want to look into quad or kd trees https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree. But that's a bit more advanced.

```
    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        for (int i = 0; i < snow_flake_count; i++) {
            Drawable snowflake = drawables.get(i);
            if( snowflake.getBounds().contains(event.getX(), event.getY())
            {
                //Do whatever you need to do
            }
        }
        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }
```